# most efficient direction to walk down the mountain

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Using function $\ f(x,y)=-x^2-y^2$ as the mountain. Currently standing at the point (2,1).

My attempt:

took partial derivative of x and y, then I got

$\ -2x $ and$\ -2y $.

What should I do next? Just simply substitute (2,1) into -2x and -2y?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE, I hope you stay around and contribute to the site :)

Comment: See ["Gradient descent"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed. You are looking for the directional derivative at $(2,1)$ and that is how you obtain it. You should be moving in *negative* gradient direction, so negate the result after you plug it in...

In fact, in optimization algorithms, you now have to solve an additional problem -- not just in which direction, but also how far to go, but this becomes a simple 1d optimization problem we can well deal with, and this is the main principle behind how many multi-dimensional optimization algorithms work.

Comment: So the (-4,-2) is where the most efficient direction?

Comment: @ZuoliZhu you should be moving in the *negative* gradient direction

Comment: Ok, make sense to me. Thanks for your help! :D